# single color Musgrave texture

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I'm trying to do a single color Musgrave texture, like transforming the white part of the Musgrave texture to be transparent, is this possible to achieve?
Attach with an example https://blend-exchange.com/b/BJj3qdx6

Answer (score 4):

This should do it - Just connect the inverse of the texture to the Alpha of the Principled BSDF.

However, since this is a Musgrave texture, which has values that go below 0, you must add a clamp node first, otherwise the invert will not work the way you expect. I also suggest adding a ColorRamp Node because there is still a thin white outline around the edges due to interpolation, which can be cut off rather easily with the ColorRamp slider. Don't forget to change your *Blend Mode* to *Alpha-Blend* or *Alpha Clip*, if you are using EEVEE.

[image: Musgrave]

Comment: Thanks @Christopher, however after doing the same as you did I'm still does not have the transparent, can you upload your blend please? 
https://i.imgur.com/5ROR1Ra.png

Comment: @greenrod you're not doing the same, you're using the **Alpha** output of your color ramp, but all your swatches have alpha set to 100%. While Christopher also has all swatches with alpha set to 100%, but he uses the **Color** output. BTW I'd advise to use the Musgrave Texture output only for the alpha, and just a flat color for the "base color" in the Principled BSDF - this way you guarantee yourself to not get any color variance on the edges other than linear transition to an object behind.

Answer (score 0):

Found - in my case the color ramp was enough to do the transparent

[image: nodes:]